# Django DEBUG = True xlsx files do not work

Tags: django, openpyxl, xlsx

I have faced a strange problem.
I have a button that creates xlsx file. For example, firstly file is empty and when I press the button it becomes full of information from the database( PostgreSQL ).

And now what is wrong:
When DEBUG is TRUE in settings.py file everything works pretty fine and the document creates. When DEBUG is FALSE it do not change the file.
I really appreciate all answers, thanks!

Comment: Please show your code. Also if it is a problem of users not being able to download the file, when DEBUG is False it means you are running on a production server. Django does not serve static / media files in a production server. check [Deploying static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/deployment/)

Answer (score 0):

One of the main features of debug mode is the display of detailed error pages. If your app raises an exception when DEBUG is True, Django will display a detailed traceback, including a lot of metadata about your environment, such as all the currently defined Django settings (from settings.py).

It is also important to remember that when running with DEBUG turned on, Django will remember every SQL query it executes. This is useful when you’re debugging, but it’ll rapidly consume memory on a production server.

Finally, if DEBUG is False, you also need to properly set the ALLOWED_HOSTS setting. Failing to do so will result in all requests being returned as “Bad Request (400)”.

source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#debug ^_^